# Excel vba dynamically choose a column from a csv into the spread sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code how can I make the columns dynamic such that I when I select a range in the spreadsheet it will only place specific column. I get the csv through an api

```
   count = Cells(Columns.Count, ActiveCell.Row).End(xlUp).Column - 
   ActiveCell.Column

    For x = 1 To count
        value(x) = Array(x, 1)
    Next x

    Sheets(1).Range(Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)), Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)).End(xlDown)).TextToColumns _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=value
```

I tried to have an input = 1 the fieldvalue would find array 1 and change the value of the array to (1,9)

```
input = 1 
FieldValue(1) = Array(1,9)
```

but this only removes the column 1, I want to be able to get column 1 only dynamically through a variable which is a user input or static using the for loop above to determine the size of the column

How can I dynamically choose a column from the csv through user input and output it anywhere in the spreadsheet?

Userform pass the value, use the value as the basis for the column, get the column and output it in the csv.

Sample CSV Data from an api/url

```
  A,B,C,D,E
  1,2,3,4,5
  6,7,8,9,10
  11,12,13,14,15
  16,17,18,19,20
```

Comment: It sounds like you only want to select a column, is that right?

Comment: What does this have to do with VB.NET? Tag removed.

Comment: Is your data sample shown all in one column? And if so, are you only trying to keep one "column" of that data as determined by the delimiter? Are you trying to make this selection by prompting user for input or setting the column of interest in the code without prompting? I think I answered a little too quickly and need more clarification.

Comment: @QHarr data sample show only in one column and I am want only one column of that data. Its not determined by a delimeter. When I type in the userform 1 I want column 1 to display.

Comment: @QHarr As you can see the data above I can output the csv data in each column and I can single out a column using Example:  Array(1,9) Array(1,1) in the fieldinfo

Comment: If comma separated then the columns are determined by the delimiter ",". Say you have A,B,C,D,E. Column 1 is A. Are you after A 1 6 11 16  as a column from the above? Without doing text to columns?

Comment: After it has been split into columns, do you then want to dynamically select a column using a userform input number?

Comment: @QHarr Yes I want it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to select a single column

`Dim colOfInterest As Long: colOfInterest = userInput` '<==This would be from user form.Pseudo code. You can also pass the outputColumn as an argument (I am assuming same sheet here).

Userform would call this sub with colOfInterest argument and output column argument.:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test(ByVal colOfInterest As Long, Optional ByVal outputColumn As Long =1)
    Dim arr(), arr2(), i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .UsedRange.Value
        ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr, 1))
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            arr2(i) = Split(arr(i, 1), ",")(colOfInterest - 1)
        Next i
       '.UsedRange.ClearContents '<==potentially clear away existing data?
       .Cells(1,outputColumn).Resize(UBound(arr2)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
Application.InputBox("Select a range", Type:=8)
```

Comment: Clarifying that my answer is relevant to this aspect of the question: "How can I dynamically choose a column from the csv through user input and output it anywhere in the spreadsheet"